# setOnClickListener not working

Tags: android

I've tried to follow the several other times this question has been asked but all other reports of what's working seem to be the same as mine, except mine doesn't work. It compiles and runs and doesn't crash, but it simply does not do what it's supposed to do. In the code, the "Alpha" error log DOES NOT occur, so it is not recognizing that it's clicked.

Here's the relevant snippet of code. Any ideas?

```
    for(int i=0; i<[big long statement]; ++i)
    {
        final TextView resourceText= new TextView(ctx);
        resourceText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        resourceText.setText([big long statement]);
        resourceText.setTextSize(18);
        resourceText.setClickable(true);
        resourceText.setFocusable(false);
        resourceText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("Alpha", "Alpha");
                resourceText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
        });
        scrollLinearLayout.addView(resourceText);
    }
```

This is where scrollLinearLayout is created

```
    //Add Linear Layout for the scrollview
    scrollLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(ctx);
    scrollLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
    scrollLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    //scrollLinearLayout.setId(MyR.Ids.ROOMDIALOGFRAGMENTLL_ID);
    resourceScrollView.addView(scrollLinearLayout);
```

Thanks

Comment: What is big long statement?

Comment: [Big long statement] is just a long statement. It's not relevant. I replaced what's in my code with that "[big long statement]"

Comment: Can you post the layout where `scrollLinearLayout` lies?

Comment: There are several errors. 1. You are comparing int to String.. 2.For each execution of loop, you are adding a view in your layout.

Comment: @AbhishekShukla: Where is the `comparing int to String`?

Comment: make sure your loop is executing.  I don't think you want to set the onClickListner in a loop multiple times

Comment: The loop is executing. The text that is created in the loop shows up. [big long statement] is not the same one both times. Just ignore it, it's not relevant.

Comment: based on what we can see here, it should work. but we can't see everything, gonna need more code to help you.

Comment: I know it's commented out, but `layout.setID(MyR.Ids.sth);`? You don't use auto-generated R?

Comment: Yeah, I use my own R. Invertigo, I wish I could post more but that's a tricky issue. I am being paid to write this code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should move the listener away from loop :

```
   for(int i=0; i<[big long statement]; ++i)
    {
        final TextView resourceText= new TextView(ctx);
        resourceText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        resourceText.setText([big long statement]);
        resourceText.setTextSize(18);
        resourceText.setClickable(true);
        resourceText.setFocusable(false);
        resourceText.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        scrollLinearLayout.addView(resourceText);
    }
    View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("Alpha", "Alpha");
                ((Button)v).setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
        };
```

Comment: This seems to have the exact same problem. Used pretty much exactly that except I casted as a TextView instead of Button and I moved the View.onClickListener to above the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

it is because your linearlayout encompasses the textview, resourceText.  If you allow the LinearLayout to consume the clicks, then the textview will never see a click.  You need to Try adding android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendents" to the LinearLayout

Comment: I tried this for all parent views, it still does the same thing. It doesn't recognize it's being clicked.

Comment: take out on the onClickListener for the LinearLayout.  If your textView now accepts clicks, then you'll know they were being consumed by the linearlayout.